# Check occurence of a string with a variable number

Tags: bash, if-statement

Check occurence of a string with a variable number
I have to check a certain condition, and that condition is that whenever somewhere in a certain url there is a line that states '[X] wrong' then return 'TestNotSuccesfull'. The X here could be '1','2,' etcetera.

I don't know how to make a statement that can check this, other then check for '1 wrong' OR '2 wrong' or '3 wrong', etc. There must be a better solution. Also because theoretically the X in 'X wrong' can lead up to multiple thousands...

Beneath the command line I made in bash that checks whether '1 wrong' occurs.

```
export result=`curl http://websiteABC.com | grep '1 wrong' | wc -l`; if [ $result -ge 1 ]; then  echo "TestNotSuccesfull"; else echo "TestSuccesfull"; fi
```

Can anyone help me out?

PS, the string that has to be checked actually is part of '(...) right, X wrong, (...)'.

Comment: Is the `curl` returning a special string like JSON? or plain text? in case of the former, use tools that know how to parse JSON like `jq` unlike `grep` which is just line-oriented

Comment: `if curl http://websiteABC.com | grep -q '[0-9] wrong'; then`... would do what you are asking, perhaps with a slight tweak if `0 wrong` is a success.

Comment: You don't have to `export` every variable: only the ones you want visible in the environment of other programs you launch from your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Regexes](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) are your friend.

```
if curl http://websiteABC.com | grep -qE '[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]* wrong'
then  echo "TestNotSuccesfull"
else echo "TestSuccesfull"
fi
```

`if` can take a complex command as it's argument, and any nonzero return evaluates as false.

`grep` can take Extended regular expressions if you use `-E`, and `-q` tells it not to send the matching lines to stdout, but just return n exit code to indicate whether they were found. `[0-9]+` means one or more numerals.

I edited the pattern. This one will not falsely report a fail on `0 wrong` but will hit on `01 wrong` or `10 wrong`, etc.

Again, c.f. the link at the beginning of my answer, but -
`[...]` is a "character class", which means it matches ONE character like any of those between the brackets. It can be elaborated with additional metacharacters:

`*` means "zero or more" of the preceding pattern, so `[0-9]*` will match *any* number of consecutive digits. This means it will match `123454321`, or an empty string... so if tested against "ab" it would match at the beginning, the end, and between the letters.

`[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*` means "any or no digits" (`[0-9]*`) followed by any nonzero digit (`[1-9]`) followed by "any or no digits" (`[0-9]*`). This allows leading zeroes, ending zeros, but not ONLY zeros. If there isn't at least one nonzero digit it fails.

Comment: Can it be more than one digit? Could there be leading zeroes? What's known to be before it on the line? How dependable is the format?

Comment: Updated the pattern to accommodate `0 wrong` as a possibility.

Comment: Actually I changed it to [1-9], because it has to be >=1, and excluding zero.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the parts of '[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*' and because of that the meaning of the total reg expression; could you tell me where to find more about the meaning of all those parts?

Comment: Edited to add some elaboration. :)